# INSERT INTO android SQL statment trouble

Tags: android, sql

I am having trouble directly inserting some data into SQLite using the INSERT INTO statment, its probably a silly mistake but I cannot find it.

```
    String sql = ("INSERT INTO task(task_goal) VALUES('ASDA');");
            this.ourDatabase.execSQL(sql);
```

Error is:

```
   table task has no column named task_goal
```

There clearly is a column named task goal, so im not sure why this error is occuring?

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TASK3 + " (" +

            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_GOAL + " TEXT NOT NULL);"       
    );
```

where:

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_GOAL = "task_goal";
private static final String DATABASE_TASK3 = "task";
```

Comment: Execute `SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master
WHERE tbl_name = 'task' AND type = 'table'`, and tell us what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have changed the Java code which defines your table after running your app at least once, but haven't updated the SQL schema.  You need to increment `DATABASE_VERSION` to tell SQLiteOpenHelper that there is a new schema, it will not check for you.

---

`DATABASE_VERSION` is a common variable that is passed to the SQLiteOpenHelper constructor, it is not universal, if you don't use this variable yourself you simply need to increment whatever value you pass to the [SQLiteOpenHelper constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29):

```
SQLiteOpenHelper (Context context, String name, 
        SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
```